# how to check name availability of storage account using JS SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

as a request from azure to have globally-unique Storage name, I'm trying to figure out a way to check if the Storage Account name is available or not using javascript SDK,
but I didnt find anything in the Azure js SDK.

I did found REST API:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/check-name-availability

but i'm not sure how to use it using javascript. and i dont want to use header and subsicropionid maunnly, I would like to use token and then try to use the api.
but if JS SDK have this function it will be great.

I did found for the container but this is not what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @azure/arm-storage package. Please refer to this sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/62662f54163b5ee41cb64a2610a1b65276b59988/sdk/storage/arm-storage/samples-dev/storageAccountsCheckNameAvailabilitySample.ts#L31

```
const client = new StorageManagementClient(credential, subscriptionId);
const result = await client.storageAccounts.checkNameAvailability(
  accountName
);
```